# Encrypting through .NET gives a Malformed ASN.1 header

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, x509certificate

I'm trying to encrypt some files for sending over the internet. The data is supposed to be AES-256-CBC encrypted, then wrapped in an SMIME envelope using a public key. Decryption is only possible if they have the private key. So pretty standard encryption stuff, really.

My Encrypt() method looks like this:

```
internal static byte[] EncryptSMIME(byte[] content, X509Certificate2 cert, string encryptionAlgh, int keySize)
{ 
   var cInfo = new ContentInfo(content);

   var mimeEnvelope = new EnvelopedCms(cInfo, new AlghorithmIdentifier(Oid.FromFriendlyName(encryptionAlgh, OidGroup.EncryptionAlghorithm), keySize));

   var recipient = new CmsRecipient(cert);

   mimeEnvelope.Encrypt(recipient);
   return mimeEnvelope.Encode();
}
```

We have a load generator that generates unencrypted files, feeds them through this method and gives back a correctly encrypted file. Running the *openssl asn1parse* tool gives back correct header data.

However, we also have a testing tool that is supposed to be able to encrypt files from disk in the same way. So I've built this hokey WinForms app that lets you select a couple files, then feeds the byte array (directly from the FileStream) through the same Encrypt() method. The resulting file is completely different, even when running the same file through both applications. For one, it's much bigger (example case: 350kb vs 548kb), and it appears to have a malformed ASN.1 header. The openssl tool gives back:

> Error in encoding
>
> 9268:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too
> long:.\crypto\asn1\asn1_lib.c:157:

I've been banging my head against this issue for a couple days now and can't find anything wrong with my implementations. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you upload wrong file somewhere? Isn't it just possible that encryptor adds base64 encoding + some headers to it?

Comment: My first guess would be that your text encodings are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem! Turns out the encrypting method wasn't the problem at all.

The LoadTesting tool was using `File.WriteAllBytes` to write the actual post-encryption file. The other one was using a `StreamWriter`, which appearantly applies a completely different encoding.

Once I replaced the StreamWriter with a call to File.WriteAllBytes (using the exact same byte array as before), the resulting file was good.